# A blank screen is created when page slides are switched

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, css-transitions

pageTransition used in vue3 and nuxt.

When I moved to the next page, I switched the screen to translateX.

However, as the screen moves, empty space occurs as much as the value of translateX.

I want to solve this.

```
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<style>
.page-enter-active,
.page-leave-active {
  transition:transform 0.4s linear;
}
.page-enter-from {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.page-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.page-leave-from {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.page-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try change the leave-from and leave-to with the correct order, and replace the `transition:transform 0.4s linear;` to `ease`

```
<style>
.page-enter-active,
.page-leave-active {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}
.page-enter-from {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.page-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.page-leave-from {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.page-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
</style>
```

and check about empty spaces, block horizontal scrolling issues during the transition, by:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```